# Ассоциативные массивы С++

Tags: c++

Можно ли как-то отключить сортировку по ключи в контейнере типа map? Допустим, есть код:

```
m["B"] = 5;
m["A"] = 8;
```

Изначально был записан элемент {"B",5}, но при добавлении в контейнер элемента {"A", 8} они автоматически поменяются местами вследствие автоматической сортировки по ключу. Вопрос, как это отключить?

Comment: Вам поиск по ключу нужен? Если нет, то можно вектор структур взять...

Comment: Храните элементы в отдельном массиве, а в `m` оставьте числовые индексы.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Да, нужен поиск по ключу

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2266179/5045688

Comment: Либо наоборот, оставить элементы в мапе, а в отдельном векторе хранить итераторы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет, нельзя. std::map рассчитан на скорость. Если вам важен порядок, то используйте vector, list, deque или подобный контейнер содержащий пары {key, value} в качестве элемента.

Comment: `std::map` рассчитан не на скорость, а именно на *сортированность*. "На скорость" рассчитан `std::unordered_map`.

Comment: и именно  std::unordered_map и  нужен автору (я так думаю)

Comment: когда говорите про скорость, не забывайте что все относительно, и нужно указать скорость чего вы имеете ввиду

Comment: @AR Hovsepyan: Судя по вопросу, автор хочет сохранения порядка вставки. А тут ему и `std::unordered_map` не поможет

Comment: @AnT,  прочитал вопрос еще раз и думаю вы правы

Comment: ИМХО, сортированность `std::map` - не самоцель, а способ ускорения поиска. А название `std::unordered_map` вообще вводит в заблуждение, т.к. элементы отсортированы. Но не по ключу, а по хешу от него.